# How do I use my desktop as a home desktop server

Tags: networking, server, remote

I have a PC which I want to use as a common server for all my devices. I want to be able to keep it in my basement and use it's gui desktop on my raspberry pi 4(I also want to plug in my 2 monitors on to that and get 2 displays), or use it's gui desktop on my laptop when I'm on my bed.

I have tried using tigervnc with xfce but that is still very slow and laggy even if all the devices are wired. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Remote desktops are laggy; fact of life. If you want to ask about the least laggy remote desktop apps, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to remote desktop into your downstairs pc, using raspberyy pi as a dumb terminal.  That is totally doable.  See here https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/ for instructions.

Another option is to just use ssh with the -Y option.  Some instructions here https://kb.iu.edu/d/bdnt.

If you are trying to connect from a windows device you will probably need to install something like xming http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/ on the windows server.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this but it is really laggy. I wanted to do something like stadia does, how google can get 60 frames per second remotely to us. I don't game but even stuff like videos on firefox are laggy.

Comment: That sounds like its a raspberry pi issue.  The lagginess on youtube is due to your browser not supporting the video accelerator on the pi. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=139138 has a discussion of the issue and recommends kweb (for the youtube problem).

Comment: Whatever you do on the pi will be a lot slower than on a normal computer (including remote desktop for the methods mentioned above).  Video in omxplayer works because it uses a dedicated graphics accelerator.  Standard remote desktoping solutions don't use it and will therefore render the remote screen slowly.  Try the remote desktop solution from a laptop using a linux on a stick just to convince yourself that it is the processor speed of the pi that  is the issue.